# How does one dismiss the 'upgrade notice' when managing upgrades with SVN?

Tags: updates, core, notices

I manage a site as a Subversion `checkout` of a tagged release (e.g. http://develop.svn.wordpress.org/tags/4.3.1 ), which means that I don't use the built-in core updater but rather just do a `svn sw` to each new tag.

The problem I've got (and it's really not a biggie) is that the "WordPress 4.3.1 is available! Please update now." message keeps appearing, even though it's telling me to update to the version that I've already got installed.

Does anyone know how to trick it into not forever telling me this?

*P.S.* It seems that there is a `dismissed_update_core` option, but I'm not sure how to manipulate it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your functions.php - or to a functionality plugin.

```
function myprefix_remove_update_nag() {
    remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu','myprefix_remove_update_nag' );
```

Comment: Good idea, and that does remove the notice — but does it mean that I'll never be notified of new versions? (Of course, I'm likely to keep up to date anyway, but still....)